# Create column referencing multiple PK's from same table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key, table

I am trying to create an table, *menu items*, to use in my front end.

Menu items can have 1 or many submenu items.

So one column must be able to contain 1 or more ID's from other menu item records.

I am not really sure how to implement this?

I have the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuItems](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [text] [varchar](100),
    [expanded] [bit],
    [URL] [varchar](100),
    [icon] [varchar](100),
    [items] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [visible] [bit]
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Where items can contain 1/many id's of other menuItems records.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *Menu items can have 1 or many submenu items. So one column must be able to contain 1 or more ID's from other menu item records.* No, backward. Add `Parent_ID` column which refers to the parent record in the same table (or NULL if the record is the most parent == roor). `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuItems]( [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ... , Parent_ID INT REFERENCES MenuItems (id), ... )`

Comment: Oh, ofcourse.. Thank you! And how can I query the list from one record with all subrecords?

Comment: Use a Recursive CTE.

Comment: For the recursive CTE it would look something like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267459/recursive-parent-child-location-relationship-cache-as-view/267486#267486) or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266128/get-the-total-count-of-every-child-foreign-keys/266245#266245).

Comment: Does someone know how to do this in C#?